# pdf viewer with a scroll button

Tags: android

so i was creating a pdf viewer and use a buttons to scroll down or up. so i tried using scrollTo but it's not working but it is working when i make a textview with a long text. is scrollTo only working in a text and not in pdf? since i'm not getting any error i don't know whats wrong the code. can someone suggest how can i make it work?

heres the xml:

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="140dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:padding="16dp">




        <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/pdfviewer"
            android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"/>
        
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lorem_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6"
            android:textColor="#000000" />


    </ScrollView>
```

my activity:

```
public class navigaze_scroll extends AppCompatActivity {

    PDFView testpdf;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigaze_scroll);
        final ScrollView scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
        Button scrollUp = findViewById(R.id.up_button);
        Button scrollDown = findViewById(R.id.down_button);



        testpdf = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfviewer);
        testpdf.fromAsset("pdf1.pdf")



                .defaultPage(0)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
                .spacing(2)
                //.pageFitPolicy(FitPolicy.WIDTH)
                .load();


        scrollUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                scrollView.scrollTo(0, scrollView.getScrollY() -24);
            }
        });

        scrollDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                scrollView.scrollTo(0, scrollView.getScrollY() + 24);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

edit: i forgot to change the scrollView to testpdf